# How to transpose data in excel from quarterly to monthly format

Tags: excel

I have the following data in Excel `sheet1`.

[image]

I would like to transpose this data into columns in another sheet. I have used the following formula to do so

```
=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!C3:J3)
```

Which gives the following output

[image]

As you can see, the first sheet is frequenced quarterly and the second sheet is frequenced monthly. When I transpose the data into the monthly sheet, is there a way to tweak this formula to  have the same number appear in all three months of a given quarter? (so for 0.83 to appear in the first three months, 2.23 in the next three months and so on?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can benefit from INDEX and MATCH (Match will work only if headers in transposed data is exactly the same than source data):

[image]

Formula in B11:

```
=INDEX($C$3:$F$4;MATCH(B$10;$B$3:$B$4;0);ROUNDUP(MONTH($A11)/3;0))
```

Drag to left and down